# Gitkraken- Push failed on refs/heads/master: protected branch hook declined

Tags: github, gitkraken

This is the first time I am pushing the master branch from local to origin environment. I just need some clarification what this error means.

> pushed failed: master Push failed on refs/heads/master: protected branch hook declined

[image: Error shown when I push from my local to orgin environment through Gitkraken]

If anyone can help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

If means the remote [GitHub master branch is protected](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches).

That [comes from](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches):

> If you're a repository owner or have admin permissions in a repository, you can customize branch protections in the repository and enforce certain workflows, such as requiring more than one pull request review or requiring certain status checks to pass before allowing a pull request to merge.

Comment: Thank you for your response and figured this was the case!